# How to properly use keylistener in java

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

I am trying to move the character in this game forward and backwards with left and right keys using `KeyListner` but I can't seem to move the character a bit. I looked at this answers with no luck:

[How to use keyListener properly in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39963925/how-to-use-keylistener-properly-in-java) and
[How do i use KeyListener in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603203/how-do-i-use-keylistener-in-java)

Here is my code:

```
package test2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Frame A1 = new Frame();
    }

}

class Frame
{
    JFrame window;

    public Frame ()
    {
        awt();
    }

    public void awt()
    {
        Design A2 = new Design()
        {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
            {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
            {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        };

        window = new JFrame("Kyo's test");

        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setSize(1280, 786);
        window.add(A2);

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}


abstract class Design extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{
    // Timer objects for character and saws
    Timer movementOfCharacter = new Timer(5, this);
    Timer movementOfSaw = new Timer(15, this);

    // Variables for movement
    int xAxisOfCharacter = 50, velocityOfCharacter=2, yAxisOfSaw = 0, velocityOfSaw = 10;

    private Image tree, background, character, saw;


    // Constructor
    Design()
    {
        movementOfCharacter.start();

        addKeyListener(this);

        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    // Constructor of Graphics
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics)
    {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);

        Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;

        graphics2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

        movementOfSaw.start();

        // Body for background
        {
            ImageIcon whale = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("whale.jpg"));
            background = whale.getImage();

            graphics2d.drawImage(background, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }

        // Body for trees
        {
            ImageIcon environment = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Tree_Alt.png"));
            tree = environment.getImage();

            graphics2d.drawImage(tree, getWidth()/8, getHeight()-217, this);
            graphics2d.drawImage(tree, (getWidth()/5)*2, getHeight()-217, this);
            graphics2d.drawImage(tree, (getWidth()/6)*4, getHeight()-217, this);
        }

        // Body for Saws of death
        {
            ImageIcon sawOfDeath = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("saw.gif"));
            saw = sawOfDeath.getImage();

            // First saw
            {
                graphics2d.drawImage(saw, (getWidth()/11), yAxisOfSaw, 100, 100, this);
            }

            // Second saw
            {
                graphics2d.drawImage(saw, (getWidth()/7)*2, yAxisOfSaw, 100, 100, this);
            }

            // Thirf saw
            {
                graphics2d.drawImage(saw, (getWidth()/2)-10, yAxisOfSaw, 100, 100, this);
            }

            // Fourth saw
            {
                graphics2d.drawImage(saw, (getWidth()/6)*4, yAxisOfSaw, 100, 100, this);
            }

            // Fifth saw
            {
                graphics2d.drawImage(saw, (getWidth()/6)*5, yAxisOfSaw, 100, 100, this);
            }
        }

        // Body for exit
        {
            graphics.setColor(Color.red);
            graphics.fillRect(getWidth()-5, getHeight()-150, 5, 150);
        }

        // Body for Character
        {
            ImageIcon blanka = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Blank.gif"));
            character = blanka.getImage();

            graphics2d.drawImage(character, xAxisOfCharacter, getHeight()-150, 150, 155, this);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        yAxisOfSaw += velocityOfSaw;

        if(yAxisOfSaw > 0 || yAxisOfSaw < getHeight()-100)
            velocityOfSaw = -velocityOfSaw;

        repaint();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            velocityOfCharacter = -5;
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            velocityOfCharacter = 5;
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
    }
}
```

Could anyone please tell me where and what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Not directly related to your question but: a painting method is for painting only. This method will get called every time you do a repaint() or when Swing determines the component needs to be painted. Therefore: 1) don't keep starting the Timer. 2) Don't keep reading the image files. This will slow down the game. All images should be read in the constructor. 3) whats with all the {....} blocks. You don't need to add a block of code for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The issue

When you do

```
Design A2 = new Design() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
};
```

You are overwriting the code your wrote in your `Design` abstract class with just throwing exceptions.

## Solutions

Your `Design` class does not have to be `abstract` as it does not have unimplemented methods. So I can see 2 ways to use the code you wrote in you `Design` class:

**First way**

Remove the `abstract` keyword so you can instantiate your `Design` class like a normal class with the `new` keyword. So declare the `Design` class this way:

```
class Design extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener
```

And then instantiate A2 this way:

```
Design A2 = new Design();
```

**Second way**

If, for some reason, you need the class to be abstract is to instantiate your A2 object this way:

```
Design A2 = new Design() {};
```

This will work and not overwrite any method you wrote in your `Design` class. But that makes little sense, the first way above makes more sense.

## Notes

**Note 1**

Now if you add a printout in your `Design.keyPressed` you can see that it is called (you will see logs in your console):

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("KeyEvent: "+e);
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    ...
```

**Note 2**

Also looking at the `keyPressed` method, I think you also need to update the character X axis coordinate, so add this line after your if statements:

```
xAxisOfCharacter += velocityOfCharacter;
```

It should look like this:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("KeyEvent: "+e);
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        velocityOfCharacter = -5;
    }
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        velocityOfCharacter = 5;
    }
    xAxisOfCharacter += velocityOfCharacter;
}
```